# Use of "zu+infinitive" in passive voice

Tags: meaning, passive

Here is a sentence:

> Abschließend freue ich mich auf die Party und bin sehr glücklich, eingeladen zu sein.

Is it possible to use the infinitive Nebensatz with passive here? Or should one instead opt for a "dass" clause? I've read that it is not correct to use infinitive with dative and genitive objects in passive voice. But it seems kinda hazy to me when it comes to accusative objects. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part "ich bin sehr glücklich, eingeladen zu sein" is fine.

The accusative object (invite someone) becomes the subject in the passive sentence (someone is/was invited).

You could also say

- "ich bin sehr glücklich, eingeladen worden zu sein"
- "ich bin sehr glücklich, dass ich eingeladen wurde".